# Temp columns in query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables, I have first table call projects and two is employees
Each employee pays his / her monthly salary divided by projects
I want to create a query that shows project names as columns and names of employees as records and contain the values of these percentages
Note Projects are changing each month

Is there a way to execute the query or not؟

example:
[image]

Comment: have you tried any code, can you please share that ?

Comment: Could you post some table data from the tables? Is that image you posted an example of what you have or what you would like?

Comment: You have both sql server and access tagged.  Please remove the one that does not apply.

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't code

Comment: I have projects, budgets and employees tables. I enter in budget values all employees to all projects

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code the following will be brief. Join all projects, budgets and employees. This will return many rows and not the columns you desire. Next create a dynamic pivot statement. This will need a distinct list of projects supplying. Next execute the statement.  [simple talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/) has a good example.